# Mongodb find in jsonArray

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to know for each employeeid is their list of competencyTitle from the mongodb in jsonArray below ;

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54510afa1abd8deb32e82a2e"),
"EmployeeID" : "6",
"CompetencyTitle" : "Chemical",
"Weightage" : 8
}

/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54510afa1abd8deb32e82a2f"),
"EmployeeID" : "6",
"CompetencyTitle" : "Biology",
"Weightage" : 6
}

 /* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54510afa1abd8deb32e82a30"),
"EmployeeID" : "7",
"CompetencyTitle" : "Processes and Procedures",
"Weightage" : 5
 }
```

The output to be something like below;

EmployeeID 6 { Chemical,Biology}
EmployeeID 7 {Processes and Procedures}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sound basically like an [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) problem. A little different in output but then again it's actually a valid structure:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$EmployeeID",
        "competencies": { "$push": "$CompetencyTitle" }
    }}
])
```

Gives simple results:

```
{
    "_id": "6",,
    "compentencies": [ "Chemical", "Biology" ]
},
{
    "_id": "7",
    "compentencies": [ "Processes and Procedures" ]        
}
```